# Tool for managing support requests from end users

Tags: users

I am looking for help desk webapp that can help a small team manage support tickets.

I would like the tool to be able to convert email received via an email address like support@mydomain.com into tickets and any subsequent replies to be added to the ticket. The tool should also have a web interface where users can log on and post new tickets and track their progress. Support team members should be able to reply to the ticket from a web based user interface.

Googling gets me lots of results but what I would really like is some recommendations of what the best ones are. I'm prepared to pay for the right piece of software but i'm not going to complain about some cheap or even free suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran an I.T. company and we used a product called [Connectwise](http://www.connectwise.com/). It's generally considered the best of its kind, and it automatically opens tickets up from emails sent in by clients.

The main competitor to ConnecWise is [AutoTask](http://www.autotask.com/). It has a good user base, too, but runs only SaaS -- no local install option.

Some additional options that might be worth checking out are [TigerPaw](http://www.tigerpawsoftware.com/) and [ShockeyMonkey](http://www.shockeymonkey.com/).

This category of software is called PSA -- professional service automation. All of the packages I suggested have avenues for billing, accounting for time, or applying the incident to a service contract of any typical type. They also will interface with some popular monitoring platforms (like [Kaseya](http://www.kaseya.com/) or [Level Platforms](http://www.levelplatforms.com/)) with the purpose of capturing support events in an automated manner and placing them on a service board for prioritization.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

I have used request tracker that does exactly what you want.
http://bestpractical.com/rt/

Bugzilla is another very popular tool, which is very popular with open source community and have used in enterprise setups too.

http://www.bugzilla.org/

Answer (score 2):

Most of the webhosters i use as vendors seem to use [Kayako](http://www.kayako.com/products/resolve/).

For what is worth, from my side as a customer is a good ticket system, I mean it works, except for some front-end bug (IE shows JS errors, but it's because I turned on IE debugger).

It's expensive 600$, but it's a one time fee.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.desk.com formerly Assitly which was acquired by SalesForce allows for 1 free account which is great. It turns emails into tickets, follows twitter and more. Another great app is Zendesk.com which recently launched a Voip service so phone calls can automatically generate tickets as well.

You can do the same with desk.com using their API and Asterisk

Comment: +1 for saying Zendesk which is actually what I ended up going with some time after I originally asked this question.

Comment: Zendesk has a great application, i'm using desk.com until I have a need for two people to manage support requests then i'll move to zendesk

Answer (score 1):

Sameer's suggestion, RT, works (and it's free); in the open source space, there's also [Sugar CRM](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/).

Answer (score 1):

I just set up [eStreamDesk](http://estreamdesk.com/) in my company.

It's e-mail based, incredibly simple, free (not opensource), integrated with Google Apps with SSO, highly customizable...

It can also work with your own domain name / e-mail.

I'm really fan of this application!

Comment: This looks pretty good, if its free but not open source how do they make their money? That always puts me off.

Comment: I asked the same question, here is there response to me: `The service is currently free and is not limited. We plan adding paid accounts with more functionality in 2011 but the existing functionality will remain free.`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest OTRS http://www.otrs.com

It's OpenSource, it's free - but you can buy commercial support if you need it